# Is there an example music on Lydian ♭2 ♭7 scale?

Tags: theory, scales

Today I found that, in 19edo, the kleismic scale has interval steps of **1 4 1 4 1 4 4**.

By setting C as the tonic, that is **C - Dbb - Eb - Fbb - Gb - Abbb - Bbb**. (where the white keys are standard diatonic/meantone keys)

By 19edo enharmony, that's equivalent to **C - C# - Eb - E - Gb - G - A#**.

By parsing this as a 12edo scale, that becomes **C - Db - Eb - Fb - Gb - Abb - Bb**.

For this scale involves many flats, I choose the fifth mode: **C - Db - E - F# - G - A - Bb**. This is interval steps of **1 3 2 1 2 1 2**.

So surprisingly, I ended up with **Lydian b2 b7** scale.

But are there any example music on this scale? The triads in this scale are rather bizarre, involving some weird augmented chords that are enharmonic to other chords: **C - F#m - Edim - F#dim - Gdim - Am - F#**.

Comment: Whereas each of the natural modes differs from then other natural modes by the subtlest difference (Dorian and Mixolydian by a single note), I fail to see why this particular scale is Lydian.it is no more a Lydian scale than a mixolydian or phrygian

Comment: @nuggethead It differs from Phrygian by 3 notes. It differs from Lydian dominant by just one note. Therefore, it should be called Lydian dominant ♭2.

Comment: About these chords, refer to https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/127519/what-chord-do-we-get-by-raising-the-fifth-of-a-minor-triad.